# Error 500 when adding or modifying membership

Tags: civimember, joomla, error-page

When manually adding without recording a membership payment or modifying a membership I am getting an an error 500. Renewing with payment from front-end and manually adding a membership when recording a payment still works.

The error happens when doing the AJAX call to:

`https://mysite.com/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contact/view/membership&action=add&cid=2180&context=membership&snippet=json`

When enabling debugging, the response contains this error:

`0 key(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given`

We have noticed this in CiviCRM 5.50.3, but it still occurs after upgrading to 5.53.0. I have also tried with PHP 7.4 and 8.0.

I am currently running on Joomla 3.10.11, CiviCRM 5.53.0 and PHP 8.0.

Edit: I could not get a backtrace because the error seems to have been caught by Joomla, not by CiviCRM. Nothing were in my logs, so I enabled debugging in Joomla to find the following:

```
An error has occurred.

    0 key(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given
    /var/www/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/BAO/Membership.php:2031 

Call stack
#   Function    Location
1   ()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/BAO/Membership.php:2031
2   key()   JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/BAO/Membership.php:2031
3   CRM_Member_BAO_Membership::setQuickConfigMembershipParameters()     JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/Form.php:444
4   CRM_Member_Form->ensurePriceParamsAreSet()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/Form.php:497
5   CRM_Member_Form->setPriceSetParameters()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/Form/Membership.php:1019
6   CRM_Member_Form_Membership->submit()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/Form/Membership.php:878
7   CRM_Member_Form_Membership->postProcess()   JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:573
8   CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php:152
9   CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->realPerform()     JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php:119
10  CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->perform()     JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203
11  HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle()     JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103
12  HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle()   JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:355
13  CRM_Core_Controller->run()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/Page/Tab.php:324
14  CRM_Member_Page_Tab->edit()     JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/Page/Tab.php:394
15  CRM_Member_Page_Tab->run()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:319
16  CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69
17  CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36
18  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke()   JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php:121
19  civicrm_invoke()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php:40
20  require_once()  JROOT/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:402
21  Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::executeComponent()    JROOT/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:377
22  Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent()     JROOT/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:101
23  Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch()     JROOT/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:159
24  Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()    JROOT/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php:225
25  Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()    JROOT/administrator/index.php:51
```

Edit 2: If it helps, this was an ancient install that was running Joomla 1.5 and CiviCRM 3.4.8 then progressively upgraded to the current version.

Comment: Could you also enable backtrace and post the full backtrace here?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JonG-MegaphoneTech, sorry for the delay. I posted the backtrace in an edit.

Comment: I don't think this is the correct backtrace, since the error is different.

Comment: You are right, I had not noticed it. It is odd though I can reproduce the error, it does not seem to produce a backtrace. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Joomla - but I know that Drupal catches certain backtraces in its "watchdog" table, and WordPress errors end up in the PHP log (in the `/var/log` folder on Debian/Ubuntu-likes).  You may want to look for your PHP log.  Note that if you use `mod_php` rather than `php-fpm` it may be in your Apache log.

Comment: I think I found the proper details of the error. From what I can figure is that it expects a price set, but none is given?

Comment: That's the correct backtrace - but looking at the code, I don't think I can resolve this without knowing more about your data - but yes, I think there's a price set problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I think I resolved my issue.

There was some HTML and JavaScript embedded in the description of one my memberships. I discovered it when inspecting the variables in **JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/BAO/Membership.php:2031** This info was relayed in the background and I am guessing PHP did not like it. After removing it, the error went away.

Thanks for the pointers Jon G!